# Any point in using a prepared statement within a sanitized-input stored proc?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I'm not a DB expert, but I've inherited some of the responsibility for a fairly large production MySQL DB from a guy who seems to have been somewhat to severely incompetent but with the occasional flares of brilliance.  Most issues I've been able to sort out myself, but this one has me stumped and I haven't seen anything addressing it anywhere:

Is there any sane reason to have a stored procedure that is nothing more than a wrapper for a prepared statement?

Something along these lines:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo_search (IN searchParam1 int, IN searchParam2 varchar(255))
BEGIN
    SET @local1 = searchParam1;
    SET @local2 = searchParam2;
    PREPARE stmt FROM 
        '...'; --Fairly complex nested select statement
    EXECUTE stmt USING @local1, @local2;
END
```

And that's it.  My understanding of prepared statements is that their benefit lies in sanitizing input (already handled by the PHP framework we use), and reducing communication back-and-forth (compromised by being within a stored proc).

Is this pure and simple pointless insanity as it appears, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike listed two good reasons. Here are a couple more:

1. Reduces the amount of network traffic as `CALL foo_search(searchParam1, searchParam2)` will be less data than sending the entire SQL statement each time.
2. Preparing the statement on the server *may* improve performance. After benchmarking several different methods, we found that for complex SQL statements, preparing the statement only once, ***on the server***, performed the best. Here's an example:

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo_search (IN searchParam1 int, IN searchParam2 varchar(255))
BEGIN
    SET @local1 = searchParam1;
    SET @local2 = searchParam2;
    IF ISNULL(@foo_search_prepared) THEN
        SET @foo_search_prepared = TRUE;

        PREPARE stmt FROM 
            '...'; --Fairly complex nested select statement
    END IF; 
    EXECUTE stmt USING @local1, @local2;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be.

Perhaps the guy was using a DB connection library that doesn't support prepared statements, so he just wanted get an equivalent effect.

Perhaps he wanted to call that stored procedure from a trigger.

Comment: I don't believe either of those were the case, but I'll double-check, thanks!